# Custom Layout for right-to-left languages in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, localization, right-to-left

I have a custom layout that extend ViewGroup class, How can I modify the layout programmatically in order to support the right-to-left languages e.g. Arabic, Farsi, etc. Which means reversing the order of layout's items or mirroring ?

Comment: there is an attribute to support RTL in xml. also, try using start and end attributes in the xml layout

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, but I have a custom layout which is implemented as a  java class file, so I need to modify it to support right to left languages.

Comment: then you're looking for `View` direction methods such as http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutDirection(int)

Comment: Thank you very much, But I need a real example if it is possible!!. because I did not know how to use these features in my java class file.

Comment: Thanks, I want to use the setLayoutDirection method, but I don't know where to add it in custom layout, in onLayout() or in onMeasure() method.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do this programmatically
starting with Android api 17 (4.2 i think), you can define dynamically where the items will be on the screen according to the device locale.

it should look something like this:

```
<TextView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:drawableLeft="@drawable/profile_settings_list_options"
     android:drawablePadding="28dp"
     android:drawableStart="@drawable/profile_settings_list_options"
     android:gravity="start"
     android:paddingBottom="16dp"
     android:paddingLeft="28dp"
     android:paddingStart="28dp"
     android:paddingTop="16dp"
     android:textColor="@color/gray_dark3"
     android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small2" />
```

For more, read this [blogpost](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html)